# Legality of publishing a homebrew campaign

Tags: dnd-5e, publishing

A friend and I are collaborating on designing a campaign setting for D&D 5e. We'd like to eventually publish it on drivethrurpg. I'm wondering about legality concerns with this. We're going to have things like Tiefling and Drow that would be part of this campaign.

I'm wondering about the legal concerns of this. It seems like I've heard a lot of horror stories about WOTC using their huge team of lawyers to step all over independent publishers.

Is there anything I need to keep in mind, or should I just follow the OGL? In the case of just following the OGL, how does one normally go about this? Do I need annotations on every single thing that comes from the OGL? I know little to nothing about legal matters. Any advice would be appreciated.

I suppose I'm asking more about the format of things and what exactly I'd have to include in the document to make it acceptable.

Comment: I believe the linked question already addresses this; let me know if you don't think it does.  Feel free and vote up etc. that other question if you think it matches what you need but just doesn't have good enough answers yet.